# how to rewrite media folders using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect 
/media/subfolder/filename to index

the subfolders are named like 12345 or 54321 and i'd like NOT to redirect subfolders that does not have this name structure.

how could i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like this?

```
RedirectMatch ^/media/[0-9]+/.+ /index.html
```

Assuming by "index" you mean "/index.html"

Comment: perfect - thanks a lot for such a quick answer!btw - sorry for not upvoting but i need more reputation point...